# How to overlay points on one image on another image

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, plot

Hi I'm new to using numpy and I'll appreciate some help with this,

I have a NumPy array say,

```
pred_array = np.array([predictions])
```

The shape of my `pred_array` is (1024, 1024, 4), I'm assuming this is RGBA.

I have another array which are points on the image that I manually labelled.

```
labelled_array = np.array([labels])
```

The shape of my `labelled_array` is (1024, 1024).

I am basically trying to overlay the manually labelled values on the prediction values (on the image) so that I can visually inspect how well my model is doing. I try to do this like this:

```
pred_array[:, :, 3] = labelled_array
```

However, I'm not getting the desired result. I'll really appreciate it if someone can put me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: If you want folks to help you, make it **EASY**. Maybe click [edit] and add code that creates a solid green, fully opaque prediction array, e.g. `pred = np.full((1024,1024,4), [0,255,0,255], dtype=np.uint8)` or similar. Then add a label array, e.g. `label = np.zeros((1024,1024),dtype=np.uint8)` then `label[100:200,100:200] = 128` then `label[700:900,10:990] = 192` And then show what you were hoping for. HTH. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks so much for this, I'll do this right away.